# Uploading files with non-latin characters to Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

Using the [S3 service implementation in Amazon's Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html) and trying to upload multi-language files to S3, and it produces 'Forbidden' errors

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; ...

When uploading a file with just latin characters, everything works fine. I tried URL-encoding file names as well but that does not seem like making any difference.

Here's the code used for uploading files:

```
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setUserMetadata(Collections.singletonMap("fileName", fileName));
        metadata.setContentType(mediaType);
        metadata.setContentLength(content.length);
        logger.info("Uploading file {}...", fileName);
        s3.putObject(bucket, fileName, fileContent, metadata);
        logger.info("Done");
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

**Edit:** I should clarify that the problem is mainly with file names themselves and not their content, when renaming a file to something using only alpahnumeric characters the upload is successful

Comment: My guess is that it's expecting text files to be encoded using UTF-8 and it will only discover that yours aren't when it encounters 'exotic' characters ('Latin' characters are largely the same in UTF-8 so it won't notice a difference)

Comment: Can you clarify if it is the filename or the file contents that contain the problem chars. What is the filename and what does it look like after you encode it?

Comment: Please give an example of a name that fails

Comment: @bhspencer Problem is only with names, the content does not affect seem like affecting the result

Comment: @g00se Anything in Russian or Lithuanian does not work, I had files named like пасспорт.jpg and pulkè.png causing this error

Comment: What happens when you do: ```metadata.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");``` ? (Make that the first statement after the ctor)

Comment: Might be useful too to see what ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));``` prints in your code

Comment: @g00se setting content-encoding does not help, the default fie encoding is UTF-8 even though this is not really relevant, the files are not uploaded from server's file system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248759/discussion-between-g00se-and-vrezh-arakelyan).

Comment: ```ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();metadata.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");```  would be a precaution worth trying